# Increase scan performance in Apache Hbase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am working on an use case and help me in improving the scan performance.

`Customers visiting our website are generated as logs and we will be processing it  which is usually done by Apache Pig and inserts the output from pig into hbase table(test) directly using HbaseStorage`. This will be done every morning. Data consists of following columns

Customerid | Name | visitedurl | timestamp | location | companyname

I have only one column family (test_family)

As of now I have generated random no for each row and it is inserted as row key for that table. For ex I have following data to be inserted into table

```
1725|xxx|www.something.com|127987834 | india |zzzz
1726|yyy|www.some.com|128389478 | UK | yyyy
```

If so I will add 1 as row key for first row and 2 for second one and so on.

```
Note : Same id will be repeated for different days so I chose random no to be row-key
```

while querying data from table where I use  `scan 'test', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter('test_family','Customerid',=,'binary:1002')"}` it takes more than 2 minutes to return the results.`

Suggest me a way so that I have to bring down this process to 1 to 2 seconds since I am using it in real-time analytics

Thanks

Comment: HBase is not designed for this kind of queries. Probably you can use MySQL instead?

Answer (score 1):

As per the query you have mentioned, I am assuming you need records based on Customer ID. If it is correct, then, to improve the performance, you should use Customer ID as Row Key.

However, multiple entries could be there for single Customer ID. So, better design Row key as CustomerID|unique number. This unique number could be the timestamp too. It depends upon your requirements.

To scan the data in this case, you need to use `PrefixFilter` on row key. This will give you better performance.

Hope this help..

Comment: Hi maddy is there any changes I need to do in hbase configurations for better performance

Comment: Yes you can do the changes in HBase configurations for better results. But for that, I need to know more about the scenarios. However, a simple performance optimization is to set scanner caching feature. It can improve your performance a lot.

Comment: I am implementing a web-service in when we click a customerid (which is a result of other queries) it have to retrieve the records related to that id which is stored in hbase table

Comment: In this scenario, just try to design the row key as suggested earlier and use scanner caching while scanning.. All the best.. :)

Comment: I have one query whether hbase returns the records within 2 or 3 seconds

Comment: Yes. it returns depending upon the scenario like amount of data fetched, amount of data in tables, schema design etc.

Comment: There ill be max 1000 records for each id and there will be 300k id present